# Maven giving error on build =Not able to recognise Java Path

Tags: java, maven

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.alexkasko.maven:jni-headers-maven-plugin:1.0.6:javah (javah) on project jni-adaptor: Cannot find JDK_HOME directory with $JDK_HOME/bin/javap and$JDK_HOME/bin/javah utilities, please check JDK_HOME environment variable -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal com.alexkasko.maven:jni-headers-maven-plugin:1.0.6:javah (javah) on project jni-adaptor: Cannot find JDK_HOME directory with $JDK_HOME/bin/javap and$JDK_HOME/bin/javah utilities, please check JDK_HOME environment variable
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke

Comment: *Cannot find JDK_HOME directory* - Error is self explanatory. There're plenty of tutorials available over the web to set the path for the JDK. Set the JDK home location corresponding to right variables so that those will accessible to maven.

Answer (score 0):

Just `set %JAVA_HOME%/bin` to your path variable.